# How to search taxonomy terms via custom field in WordPress=

Tags: php, wordpress

I have taxonomy Shops and in it custom field location (I am generating custom field with Advanced Custom Fields plugin). It works very good.

But now, In my template file I need to find all Shops terms that have a custom field location == "London".

I searched for two hours how to search terms via custom fields but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create a custom loop :

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('category__in='.  $category_id  .'&orderby=rand&post_type=your_post_type&posts_per_page=-1&meta_key=location&meta_value=london');
```

Of course you can drop any paramater that you do not need ( category_id,orderby,posts_per_page etc .. )

ref : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy Metadata](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/) This plugin may help full for you.